# validate string in parameter block in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to validate a domain in my script like:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 2)]
[ValidateSet("abc.white", "abc.black","fr.dom.net", "gr.dom.net","bg.dom.net","sk.dom.net")]
[string] $domain
```

I'd like to get rid of xxx.dom.net having something like: *.dom.net
I know it must be done with regex, but I don't get it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use `ValidatePattern` instead but it doesn't give you result completion

Comment: Questions is unclear. You want to get rid from the list but you still want to accept "fr.dom.net"?

Comment: `[ValidatePattern('^[\w\-]+\.dom\.net$')]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  
it works nicely, but since it's not possible (?)  to have more than one validationpattern to validate a string, how to put together the domains like this: abc.white.net, bcd.black.net, and all the rest (*.dom.net) in one validation? I know, regex, I'm really struggling  with them..

Comment: You can construct a pattern that matches either: `[ValidatePattern('^(?:abc\.black|abc\.white|[\w\-]+\.dom\.net)$')]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen great, thank you. There is no excuse for me, I've to start understanding the regex....